# Using Dapper.net can I get the schema for the query I am issuing?

Tags: dapper

i.e. if the query returns 0 rows, I still would like to know the list of columns returned.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method that returns an IDataReader - possibly ExecuteReader or similar - that tells you everything you want to know about the schema. However, with dapper it would be largely expected that you know what the schema looks like ahead of time.